# SQL Server: How to unlock a table / row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

We recently updated our WPF application to perform its data synchronisation (using sync framework) within a single transaction against our SQL Server 2008 database.

Almost straight away this has somehow led to a row being locked in of of the tables 
preventing all other users from syncing.

The thing is that the lock does not seem to be lifting and we are not sure how to resolve the situation.

Any feedback appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to release a row lock is to commit or rollback the transaction in which the lock was taken.

Comment: righto - I guess eventually it will lift when whatever user that is in the process of performing a (very slow) udpate completes or cancels.